# Run iOS Application from Command Line

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, build, automation

I am in process of doing some Continuous Integration work under which i would download the .ipa from the server install it on the device and finally need to invoke the application installed and perform some automated tests.

I have been able to figure out on how i would download the .ipa from server and deploy it on the device(using ios-deploy) but i am stuck on how can i automatically invoke the application. I know i can do this via Instruments but i don't want to follow that path.
Is there any way this can be done??

P.S - I am not using Instruments for Automation.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a try with ios-deploy ? here is the link https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy